# regex forward slash alpha/numeric

Tags: regex, slash

Is it possible to parse a string and where ever there is an alpha on either side of a / drop the / and insert a space, but do not do it to numerics.  So "black/teal" would be "black teal" and of course 3/4 stays.
I dont know how to start, but do know what I cant do.I need to indicate word before the slash, word after the slash but there can be no space before the slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the replace method (tokens may vary depending on your regex flavor)

Regex:

```
(?i)([a-z])/([a-z])
```

Replacement String

```
\1 \2
```

Comment: Thank you all, Ron for the first.  Would edify me a bit more. I have never seen this syntax.  What is the (?i) Does the ()create the tokens? Finally what is the syntax to actually produce the resultant string?

Comment: @cp. In some regex flavors (?i) sets the case insensitive options.  The ( ) creates capturing groups. Fine details will depend on the regex flavor and language you are using.  But you should be able to figure that out from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify the language, here's the general idea:

Look for:

```
(\D)/(\D)
```

Replace with:

```
\1 \2
```

I.e. catch the characters before and after the slash in groups and "re-insert" them with a space inbetween.

(FYI, `\D` is any non-digit.)

Comment: You were fine until the last line -- \w also matches digits.

Answer (score 0):

something like ths in javascript

```
var str = 'black/tea/3/4';
var res = str.replace(/([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)/, '$1 $2');
console.log(res);
```